# How to stop element moving with position fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

Is there any chance to stop element moving which is have `postion: fixed;` in CSS?

I know that i could't do this with CSS, maybe is there any opction to make this solve by JS?

I've try with removeing some values by scrolling like this but...

```
$(window).scroll(function()
{   var main_menu = $('.main_menu');
    var current_position = $(this).scrollTop();
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        main_menu.css('top','0'-current_position+'px');
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<section class="content_block">
    <section id="logo_main"></section>
    <div class="main_menu">

    </div>
</section>
```

Section `content block` have `overflow: hidden`, and menu is a little more wider than parent block. So i use `position fixed` for stop stretching main section...

Is there anybody who have idea how to do this?

Comment: So... Absolute positioning?

Comment: How come your element is moving if `position: fixed` is applied to it?

Comment: i have oveflow: hidden by parent block and i neeed to do this with fixed

Comment: Element cannot move with `position:fixed`. If you scroll page, then it will still fixed at that position but scrolling is active. Is this you sayin?